# Meteorjs limit is not working

Tags: meteor

I am struggling a lot to find out why limit is not working. The same code is working from console but when I written in the template it is not working. Please help me to resolve this.

```
var balls = Balls.find({ }, {sort :{ created_at: -1}, limit : 3}).fetch();
```

Exception from Meteor._atFlush: TypeError: Cannot call method 'containerNode' of undefined

Comment: Just a thought: the console would be server side while the template would be client side. Does this same code work in your project on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my mistake; I was trying to load the balls before subscribing to the `Balls` collection.